# Seeking floorplan design VCL toolbar

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl

I'm looking for a VCL component for C++ builder. It should preferably have a toolbar with drag & drop functionality.

I want to define a building or area (which might not be rectangular) and split it into "rooms" (or areas, or whatever you want to call them). And I want to be able to put "doorways" (or passages, etc) from a room into its neighbours.

is there such a thing? Preferably free.

Thanks.

---

In case anyone wants to know the answer, I have verified with TMS that the diagram studio can indeed do this.

Although they said "You can use [TMS Diagram Studio](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/diagram.asp) for that, it’s not that complicated to create new custom blocks, like L-shaped rooms", so I still need to verify that it can handle triangles & lost parrots (polygons).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not that it is specifically built for room designing, but my best guess is that it is the closes you'll get without having to create the components yourself. Anyway TMS have a component pack called [Diagram Studio](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/diagram.asp). This allows you to add functionality to your application that somewhat simulates that of Microsoft Visio and other programs.

[image]
I don't know if this was truly what you wanted, but even though I haven't tried it myself my guess is that you can create your own room and door like shapes to be placed. It might worth a look. Atleast the feature list has this:

Comment: Timely! I was just about to buy another TMS component pack, so now it looks like I should spring for the whole bundle.

If anyone else is interested, Bruno at TMS was extremely helpful and even willing to do minor customization on one component, though you get the source & can hack it yourself.

Tommy, if you don't mind, I'll leave this for a day or two, in the unliekely event that soemoen can actually point out exactly the component that I need. But I woudl guess that you're going to be awarded the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Tommy. I subscribed to all components!

Comment: And, years later, I can't thanks Bruno, Wagner, etc enough for all of their help over the years, including help with both design and code