# Looking for non-rectangular panel VCL component

Tags: delphi, components, c++builder, vcl

Sometimes I want L-shaped, T-shaped, triangular, polygonal ...

Free reusable component please . . .

Comment: Nowadays, we can ask questions like this at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seemed to be too late, but I know a free one on the [Angus's site](http://angusj.com/delphi/).("Drawing Objects")  . (I misunderstood what you need is like non-recutanglular **form** like [TRzShapeForm](http://www.raize.com/DevTools/RzComps/ComponentList.asp) from your question.)

Sorry.

[image: angus's Drawing Objects]
<sub>(source: [angusj.com](http://angusj.com/delphi/drawobj3.png))</sub>

Comment: I noticed he dropped this component from his site. (This answer might be increase requests or questions..). You can download this component from internet archive (at least now March 13, 2013.) http://wayback.archive.org/web/20100926090549/http://angusj.com/delphi/

Answer (score 4):

There is a number of possibilities here, one of which is to implement your own component, derive from `TPanel` and use the a region to specify the area of the panel, this could be done by a call to the Windows API function [CreatePolygonRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183511%28VS.85%29.aspx). You would probably have to realign the child controls manually.

If you don't need the panel to contain any child controls, you should consider using shape objects (`TShape`) instead, you could use a combination of existing ones, or create your own.

One other option is to use regular panels, and draw the shape as background on them. The easiest way to do this might be to implement your own `TPanel` class and handle the paint code. This will not shape the panel, but you can simulate the visual features of it. If you need child components you might need to override the `Realign` function to make sure child components are kept within shaped panel boundaries.

Alternatively you have to try your luck on the internet finding 3rd party components that implements this, I did a quick search but found no panels that could do this specifically, although I must admit my search wasn't too thorough, you might have better luck than me.

Comment: yes, Tommy, I know that I can code my own. I even know how; but I also know that it will be a pain in the posterior to do so - which is why I hoped for a free component which would save me form re-inventing too much of the wheel.

(btw, then panel does need to support child-controls; it needs to support *everything* that TPanel does. I need a sub-class)

And, yes, I do know how to use google. I'm here because, like you, I found nothing (after a rigorous serach)

Comment: mawg - maybe you should state in your question that you are looking for an existing free reusable component

Answer (score 0):

I purchased http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/products.asp?t=vclp   which looks like it can do what I want (and provides source code in case it only does 90% of what I want)

See also [Seeking floorplan design VCL toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040160/seeking-floorplan-design-vcl-toolbar)